# TFS Build is Successful, but why does it not deploy anything to the Target Systems Folder

Tags: tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to create a TFS build in VS 2017. This is a Web Deploy. I have been able to get the build to create and run successfully but when I check the target system's folders, nothing is updated. On the other hand, I can get this to work if I press the "Publish" button in Visual Studio. As you can see below I have validated my connection.

Is there anything missing in my TFS Process specifically in the MSBuild arguments that I am missing? Or is it something in my publish profile in Visual Studio? Also, is there anywhere I can check some logs? I checked the logs under Inetpub, but I didn't see anything.

Below is my publish profile configuration:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>KFSS_DEV</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>bushknapp03dev.chicagobooth.edu</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>kiltsfiles-dev.chicagobooth.edu</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName>gsb\ssa-ap-devapps</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
    <PublishDatabaseSettings>
      <Objects>
        <ObjectGroup Name="KiltsFileSelectionSystemConnectionString" Order="1" Enabled="False">
          <Destination Path="" />
          <Object Type="DbDacFx">
            <PreSource Path="Data Source=bushkndb01dev;Initial Catalog=KiltsFileSelectionSystem;Integrated Security=True" includeData="False" />
            <Source Path="$(IntermediateOutputPath)AutoScripts\KiltsFileSelectionSystemConnectionString_IncrementalSchemaOnly.dacpac" dacpacAction="Deploy" />
          </Object>
          <UpdateFrom Type="Web.Config">
            <Source MatchValue="Data Source=bushkndb01dev;Initial Catalog=KiltsFileSelectionSystem;Integrated Security=True" MatchAttributes="$(UpdateFromConnectionStringAttributes)" />
          </UpdateFrom>
        </ObjectGroup>
        <ObjectGroup Name="KiltsFileSelectionSystemEntities" Order="2" Enabled="False">
          <Destination Path="" />
          <Object Type="DbDacFx">
            <PreSource Path="Data Source=bushkndb01dev;Initial Catalog=KiltsFileSelectionSystem;Integrated Security=True;Application Name=EntityFramework" includeData="False" />
            <Source Path="$(IntermediateOutputPath)AutoScripts\KiltsFileSelectionSystemEntities_IncrementalSchemaOnly.dacpac" dacpacAction="Deploy" />
          </Object>
          <UpdateFrom Type="Web.Config">
            <Source MatchValue="metadata=res://*/KiltsFilesModel.csdl|res://*/KiltsFilesModel.ssdl|res://*/KiltsFilesModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=bushkndb01dev;initial catalog=KiltsFileSelectionSystem;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" MatchAttributes="$(UpdateFromConnectionStringAttributes)" />
          </UpdateFrom>
        </ObjectGroup>
        <ObjectGroup Name="TelerikVSXConnectionString" Order="3" Enabled="False">
          <Destination Path="" />
          <Object Type="DbDacFx">
            <PreSource Path="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TelerikVSX.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" includeData="False" />
            <Source Path="$(IntermediateOutputPath)AutoScripts\TelerikVSXConnectionString_IncrementalSchemaOnly.dacpac" dacpacAction="Deploy" />
          </Object>
          <UpdateFrom Type="Web.Config">
            <Source MatchValue="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TelerikVSX.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" MatchAttributes="$(UpdateFromConnectionStringAttributes)" />
          </UpdateFrom>
        </ObjectGroup>
        <ObjectGroup Name="ApplicationServices" Order="4" Enabled="False">
          <Destination Path="" />
          <Object Type="DbDacFx">
            <PreSource Path="Data Source=bushkndb01dev;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=True" includeData="False" />
            <Source Path="$(IntermediateOutputPath)AutoScripts\ApplicationServices_IncrementalSchemaOnly.dacpac" dacpacAction="Deploy" />
          </Object>
          <UpdateFrom Type="Web.Config">
            <Source MatchValue="Data Source=bushkndb01dev;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=True" MatchAttributes="$(UpdateFromConnectionStringAttributes)" />
          </UpdateFrom>
        </ObjectGroup>
      </Objects>
    </PublishDatabaseSettings>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>True</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <MSDeployParameterValue Include="KiltsFileSelectionSystemConnectionString-Web.config Connection String">
      <UpdateDestWebConfig>False</UpdateDestWebConfig>
    </MSDeployParameterValue>
    <MSDeployParameterValue Include="$(DeployParameterPrefix)KiltsFileSelectionSystemEntities-Web.config Connection String" />
    <MSDeployParameterValue Include="$(DeployParameterPrefix)TelerikVSXConnectionString-Web.config Connection String" />
    <MSDeployParameterValue Include="ApplicationServices-Web.config Connection String">
      <UpdateDestWebConfig>False</UpdateDestWebConfig>
    </MSDeployParameterValue>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is the results of my TFS Build:

I set up my publish profile under KFSS_DEV, validated connection to Target System.

[image]

[image]

Also, here is the TFS Build Process:

[image]

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? That's a XAML build, which has been deprecated for more than 5 years.

Comment: Our TFS Version is Version 16.131.28601.4

Comment: TFvcTemplate.14.xaml

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel Are you able to get more information if you set the logging verbosity to *diagnostic*? How's the result if you deploy from MSBuild command line manually on build agent machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting  the logging verbosity to `diagnostic`, and adding `/p:OutDir="xxxxx"` argument in build definition.

By the way, it's recommended to [migrate from XAML builds to new builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/migrate-from-xaml-builds?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thank you all. I will try these suggestions. I cannot change the way we do our builds, I have to stay consistent with my team. Also, one more thing ths build is being deployed on a brand new server that this is the first application to be deployed there. Our server was retired because it was R2008, now we are at the most current level.